# Change \footcite style

Tags: biblatex, chicago-style

I use \footcite and \endnote for my note (I copied the related part only).

```
\documentclass[report, 10.5pt, a4paper, oneside, openany, dvipdfmx]{jsarticle}
%--citation
\usepackage[backend=bibtex,notes,isbn=false]{biblatex-chicago}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\addbibresource{ref}  
\usepackage{endnotes}
\let\footnote=\endnote

\begin{document}
A Sentence 1 \footcite[25]{Lancaster2008}.
A Sentence 2 \footcite[10]{Lancaster2008}.

\theendnotes
\clearpage
\renewcommand{\refname}{Bibliography}
\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

It gives me like this for the first citation:

> Carol Lancaster, *Foreign Aid: Diplomacy, Development, Domestic
>   Politics* (Chicago: University of Chicago Press, 2008), 25.

However, since I also have a bibliography part, what I want to have in the note section is:

> Lancaster, *Foreign Aid: Diplomacy, Development, Domestic Politics*, 10.
>   Wright, ‘How Foreign Aid Can Foster Democratization’. 
>   Bermeo, ‘Myths of Moderation’, 554-557.

Author (family) name, title, and page number (if specified) is what I want (more details are [here](http://www.tandf.co.uk/journals/authors/style/reference/tf_ChicagoEB.pdf)).

 
I think this is the same as what we can get for the second citation. Is there any way to get this from the first time citation?

Comment: The package has a `short` option that you may use: "This option means that your text will only use the short note form, even in the first citation of a particular work." See p. 61 in version 0.9.9g (beta) of the manual.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add "short" option (I greatly thank @jon's suggestion).

```
\usepackage[backend=bibtex,notes,isbn=false,short]{biblatex-chicago}
```